# Letsencrypt, nginx and virtual servers on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, nginx, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt

I am using a [useful tool](https://github.com/kaienkira/acme-client) to automate the creation and renewal of SSL certs from [letsencrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/). I have "parametised" the steps shown on the linked site, so that I can use the instructions to obtain and maintain SSL certs for multiple websites.

I am running nginx on Ubuntu 16.0.4 LTS. I am running multiple virtual servers with nginx.

I managed to successfully obtain certificates for the first domain (foo.com, www.foo.com, mail.foo.com), so I know that my "parametisation" of the steps/script etc works.

I am now trying to obtain a certificate for the other websites. I am trying to obtain certs for foobar.com, www.foobar.com, mail.foobar.com and staff.foobar.com.

When I run my getcert.sh script (modified for foobar.com), it returns with the following message:

```
memyself@yourbox:/opt/sslcert/foobar# su -s /bin/bash -c '/opt/sslcert/foobar/bin/getcert.sh' sslcert
acme/challenge failed: {
  "type": "http-01",
  "status": "invalid",
  "error": {
    "type": "urn:acme:error:unauthorized",
    "detail": "Invalid response from http://mail.foobar.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/RsX0GNAPx-ODGvMTHCjQ9uSru7AazwkmmG6gmo-yAkk: \"\u003chtml\u003e\r\n\u003chead\u003e\u003ctitle\u003e404 Not Found\u003c/title\u003e\u003c/head\u003e\r\n\u003cbody bgcolor=\"white\"\u003e\r\n\u003ccenter\u003e\u003ch1\u003e404 Not Found\u003c/h1\u003e\u003c/center\u003e\r\n\u003chr\u003e\u003ccenter\u003e\"",
    "status": 403
  },
  "uri": "https://acme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/challenge/83fRVxQHUjMUHzqK2Cc0gTflM_3wuwuItW5-Y6Xlfo0/360341585",
  "token": "RsX0GNAPx-ODGvMTHCjQ9uSru7AazwkmmG6gmo-yAkk",
  "keyAuthorization": "RsX0GNAPx-ODGvMTHCjQ9uSru7AazwkmmG6gmo-yAkk.9CRniSJOopxytAkBrkdIFkhM5tJzGI6kbXfB0998SNk",
  "validationRecord": [
    {
      "url": "http://mail.foobar.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/RsX0GNAPx-ODGvMTHCjQ9uSru7AazwkmmG6gmo-yAkk",
      "hostname": "mail.foobar.com",
      "port": "80",
      "addressesResolved": [
        "66.228.37.10"
      ],
      "addressUsed": "66.228.37.10"
    }
  ]
}
```

A few points worth mentioning:

1. The nginx configuration for foo.com and foobar.com are identical (except where the server name is specified)
2. The folder structure and permissioning is exactly the same for the websites foo and foobar.
3. The websites have the same physical static IP address, but different server names; i.e. the different domain names resolve to the same IP address.

Here are the contents of the error log AFTER I have tried to obtain certificates for **foobar**:

```
memyself@yourbox:~# cat /var/log/nginx/error.log
2016/11/19 10:07:41 [error] 30345#30345: *78 open() "/opt/sslcert/foo/acme-challenge/1aLrSYLJGhDBtihuoXAsdh1K0jpdmcWBYWYPGxFNJXo" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 66.133.109.36, server: foo.com, request: "GET /.well-known/acme-challenge/1aLrSYLJGhDBtihuoXAsdh1K0jpdmcWBYWYPGxFNJXo HTTP/1.1", host: "mail.foobar.com"
```

As can be seen from above, the cert is being attempted to be read from `/opt/sslcert/foo/acme-challenge/` this should be `/opt/sslcert/foobar/acme-challenge/` instead.

Can anyone explain what is causing this problem ? - and how can it be resolved?

Comment: Those two errors look unrelated. No such file or directory should return a 404, but the ACME challenge receives a 403. Are you sure that the nginx user has access to everything on the path to `acme-challenge`? Create a file in there and see if you can reach it from the domain.

Answer (score 0):

a time saver suggestion, add this location block in your server blocks and try

```
location ~ /.well-known {
      allow all;
      root /path/to/webroot/;         
}
```

if you have no problem using another command (which am using):

```
/opt/letsencrypt/letsencrypt-auto certonly -a webroot --webroot-path="/path/to/webroot/" -d "domain_name1" -d "domain_name2" --non-interactive  --email="you@email.com" --agree-tos
```

NOTES :

- Assuming you installed letsencrypt installation path as /opt/letsencrypt/
- Tested on Ubuntu 14.04 & 16.04, hope there is no problem using it in any linux systems
- if you are using new [certbot](https://github.com/certbot/certbot) rename letsencrypt-auto to certbot-auto

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look at how lets-nginx is doing this? It sounds like you're trying to do essentially what it is doing in its [entrypoint.sh](https://github.com/smashwilson/lets-nginx/blob/master/entrypoint.sh) script but inside a container.

It might even be easier to use a docker container for this entirely but if you can't this might help guide you through the setup of a script.