# Will using proxy_pass affect letsencrypt installation?

Tags: ssl, nginx, ssl-certificate, digital-ocean, lets-encrypt

I have a website eg. domain.net
and have ran certbot/letsencrypt installation successfully on my nginx/centos server.

The domain is secure and looking great. Now I have added a ghost blog to the site which I would like to encrypt eg. blog.domain.net.

This blog is setup on a different root folder than the original website, but same server. I am using a proxy_pass on :2000 to setup the subdomain.

Now the only thing I have changed is I added

```
location ~ /.well-known {
allow all;
}
```

to the blog.domain.net.conf file within my sites-available nginx. 
I have also tried adding this to the conf.d/domain.net.conf file as well with no avail :(

Whenever I run certbot per the installation instructions, it is outputting this error.

```
Failed authorization procedure. blog.domain.net (http-01): urn:acme:error:unauthorized :: The client lacks sufficient authorization :: Invalid response from http://blog.domain.net/.well-known/acme-challenge/FVQmSHuCmeiOObPDOCiD2OFP8Ivvst5n2ZwIZoeXGU8: "<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>"

IMPORTANT NOTES:
 - The following errors were reported by the server:

   Domain: blog.domain.net
   Type:   unauthorized
   Detail: Invalid response from
   http://blog.domain.net/.well-known/acme-challenge/FVQmSHuCmeiOObPDOCiD2OFP8Ivvst5n2ZwIZoeXGU8:
   "<html>
   <head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
   <body bgcolor="white">
   <center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
   <hr><center>"

   To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was
   entered correctly and the DNS A record(s) for that domain
   contain(s) the right IP address.
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Thank you

- EDIT *

Code inside sites-available/blog.domain.net.conf

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  blog.domain.net www.blog.domain.net;

    # note that these lines are originally from the "location /" block
    root  /var/www/blog.domain.net/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header HOST $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:2000;
        proxy_redirect off;
  }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Code inside conf.d/blog.domain.net.conf

```
# upstream ghost {
#    server 127.0.0.1:2000;
# }

server {
    listen      80;
    server_name blog.domain.net;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/ghost.access.log;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/ghost.error.log;

    proxy_buffers 16 64k;
    proxy_buffer_size 128k;

    location ~ /.well-known {
       /var/www/blog.domain.net/html;
    }

location / {
        proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:2000;
        proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
        proxy_redirect off;

        proxy_set_header    Host            $host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are running Letsencrypt install with --web-root option, if so set web root to `/var/www/html/` or path where an HTML content is place; then

```
location ~ /.well-known {
   root /var/www/html;
}
```

this location block should be placed above all other like `location /` where you may specified `proxy_pass` option, i already answered a letsencrypt question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40929716/3872951), check it with your install command.

Comment: Hi @sideeffect0 !

Thanks for the help! I tried your recommendation and unfortunately it doesn't seem to have changed anything :( 
I have posted an edit to my question with the code for the proxy pass in the nginx/sites-available directory as well as the nginx/conf.d directory

Comment: First 'site-enabled' directory is used to handled active nginx configuration, run nginx reload, and also comment how you are running let'sencrypt installer

Comment: It's not the 'sites-enabled' but the 'sites-available' folder, although I guess they are chained/linked right. 

Anyways, I ran sudo nginx -t and it gives me 'unknown directive "/var/www/blog.domain.net/html" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/blog.domain.net.conf'

Comment: You missed `root` before path, check my answer for reference, try to add your let'sencrypt installer command also to the question

Comment: Solved your problem ?

Comment: The cert only encryption didn't fail this time! My blog is still returning a 'privacy error' from chrome, but I think I just need to finish some more steps and it should be good. I will mark your answer correct once I confirm!

Comment: I'm so close! The SSL is working and page is displaying as secure however now my blog content is replaced by a 403 forbidden error :(

Comment: I've marked your answer as correct sideffect, since it was the solution to my original problem! Thanks again for your help. I haven't been able to get pass this 403 error, but have created another question if you'd like to take a stab. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42235571/do-i-need-two-separate-ssl-conf-files-if-i-am-hosting-multiple-domains-on-same-s Thanks again!