# Do I need two separate ssl.conf files if I am hosting multiple domains on same server?

Tags: ssl, nginx, digital-ocean, lets-encrypt

I have installed SSL successfully for my main domain eg. domain.net and www.domain.net

I am now trying to enable SSL into the blog on the website eg. blog.domain.net and www.blog.domain.net

I have gone through the installation and everything has been a success, however after restarting nginx when I visit 'blog.domain.net.conf' it is returning a '403 Forbidden' error now.

I have tried doing:

```
sudo chown -R root:root /usr/share/nginx/html/*
sudo chown -R dev:dev /usr/share/nginx/html/*
sudo chmod -R 0755 /usr/share/nginx/html/*
```

along with checking permissions of the site root but nothing is effecting it. The only thing I can think of that is different between the main domain and the blog is that I do have an ssl.conf file located in my conf.d/ folder that is only specifying the main domain.. do I need to add the blog into this file as well? If so, how can I add more than one domain into it if they share different paths?

**SSL.CONF**

```
server {
        listen 443 http2 ssl;

        server_name domain.net www.domain.net;

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.net/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.net/privkey.pem;

        ########################################################################
        # from https://cipherli.st/                                            #
        # and https://raymii.org/s/tutorials/Strong_SSL_Security_On_nginx.html #
        ########################################################################

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_ciphers "EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH";
        ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1;
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
        ssl_session_tickets off;
        ssl_stapling on;
        ssl_stapling_verify on;
        resolver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 valid=300s;
        resolver_timeout 5s;
        # Disable preloading HSTS for now.  You can use the commented out header line that includes
        # the "preload" directive if you understand the implications.
        #add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; preload";
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains";
        add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;

        ##################################
        # END https://cipherli.st/ BLOCK #
        ##################################

        ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;

        location ~ /.well-known {
                allow all;
        }

        # The rest of your server block
        root /var/www/domain.net/html;
        index index.php  index.html index.htm;

        location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

I am also doing a proxy pass for the sub-domain/blog
**blog.conf**

```
# upstream ghost {
#    server 127.0.0.1:2000;
# }

server {
    listen      80;
    server_name blog.domain.net www.blog.domain.net;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/ghost.access.log;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/ghost.error.log;

    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;

    proxy_buffers 16 64k;
    proxy_buffer_size 128k;

    location ^~ /.well-known {
      allow all;
      root /var/www/blog.domain.net/html;
    }

location / {
        proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:2000;
        proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
        proxy_redirect off;

        proxy_set_header    Host            $host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    }

}

server {

    # SSL configuration

    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
    include snippets/ssl-blog.domain.net.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

}
```

Could my proxy pass be what is affecting this? 
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Why is `upstream ghost` partially commented out - you have an unmatched brace?

Comment: Sorry! That was just a bad copy/paste job on my part. It's all commented out.

Comment: @user3648969 how you generated ssl cert, which domain you specified ?
you need to specify the `domain.com', 'sub.domain.com'  while generating; For example `-d "domain_name1" -d "domain_name2"`

Comment: @sideffect0 I used this command for the ssl cert.
sudo certbot certonly -a webroot --webroot-path=/var/www/blog.domain.net/html -d domain.net -d www.domain.net

Is this correct? It said 'congratulations' etc.. afterwards but when visiting the domain it says 'secure' in the URL but page is showing a 403 Forbidden nginx

Comment: @user3648969 one thing to note, you dont need `well-know` block, after getting ssl cert from letsencrypt

Comment: location ^~ /.well-known {
      allow all;
      root /var/www/blog.domain.net/html;
    }

So I can remove this full location block? Could that be related to the 403 forbidden?